# how to get REAL size of a device?

Tags: javascript, screen-size

I have this problem:
I want to code a website that displays differently according to used device.
What I'd like is something like:

```
if (screen.width < 400) useLayout(1);
else if (screen.width >=400 and screen.width < 800) useLayout(2);
else useLayout(3);
```

now the problem is that when i code for mobile device the
screen width reported by javascript is the one I set using metatag viewport.
So if I create a file with:

```
<meta id='viewport' name='viewport' content='width=410'>
```

then when using javascript (both `window.screen.width` and `document.documentElement.clientWidth`) the returned value is exactly 410. This value does not reflect the REAL display size...

What I really need is to understand how many inches (or cm) are 100pixel on that device...

is there any way?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this is tagged JavaScript, but I believe it is not the appropriate solution. CSS has this built in. It's much better to keep your design layer out of the scripts as much as possible. Look into CSS Responsive Design / [Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).

Example:

```
@media screen and (max-width:399px) { 
    body {
        background-color : 'red';
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width:400px) and (max-width:799px) { 
    body {
        background-color : 'blue';
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width:800px) { 
    body {
        background-color : 'green';
    }
}
```

You could also segregate those into their own CSS files to minimize redundant CSS data transfer for non-applicable users:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width:399px)" href="layout1.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width:400px) and (max-width:799px)" href="layout2.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width:800px)" href="layout3.css" />
```

To answer your question about the inaccuracy of the screen with from JS, it's [not so cut and dry](http://tripleodeon.com/2011/12/first-understand-your-screen) and needs some room for [interpretation variances](http://tripleodeon.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/table.html).

Comment: It still does not work:
if I set meta tag, viewport = 410 then the screen is blue
if I set meta tag, viewport = 800 then the screen is green
So again the result depends on how I did set the viewport and not depends on the "real" device size...

Comment: just to clarify my purposes: let's take in account an old Galaxy mobile with 320x240 and a new one with 720x1280. Let's say I write somethinf with font size=14px on 320x240 and it is readable, it will not on the 720x1280.... so on that case I shoule be able to understand that and change font size (in my case I would change also the html file used)

Comment: So why are you setting the viewport value at all if it's causing all your conflicts? Just leave it as `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`